# Request permission to perform Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a project where I need make cross-origin requests, but there does not appear to be any way to allow this in a pure web page.

Chrome extensions can simply request permission to the domains they would like to make requests to as in the following example.

```
"permissions": [
  "http://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/"
]
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

I found https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/no_crx which seemed like something closer to what I was looking for, but the only permissions allowed are "geolocation", "notifications", and "unlimitedStorage".

There is the HTTP header Access-Control-Allow-Origin which could be set on the domains I would like to make requests to, but they are not under my control so that is not practical.

Similarly the Content-Security-Policy: connect-src https://www.google.com; is primarily used to further restrict access instead of opening up access.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

I understand the security concerns, but as a quick search will show people get around this by making a proxy server. Wouldn't it make sense to allow the equivalent request to be made, meaning a request without the user's session/cookie information (like incognito mode)? Or some mechanism by which the page can request permission in the same manner as an extension? Seems somewhat backwards to require things like this to be down in browser specific manner.

Just like webspeech api (or getUserMedia) requests access to use microphone.

Any thoughts or perhaps something I missed?

EDIT: I posted this elsewhere and got:

If you are making requests from domains that are under your control, there are other options (like JSONP) that you can use to access data from another domain. Or, you can load an iframe and use postMessage() to interact with the contents - there are lots of tools that also enforce that the domain you're trying to communicate with is willing to share that data.

Me:

JSONP looks like a solution for data sources that provide JSON, but I am not sure that will solve my overall problem. I am trying to create a tool that will pull in data from a variety of sources to do both displaying a result and interpreting the information to perform an action. One query might be a google search which jsonp or the other official methods should allow for, but that does not work for scraping data from other web pages. All of the requests being made will not require user session information and thus a proxy would work, but will add latency and maintenance costs.

The postMessage() interface would require the pages being requested to implement listeners right?

So far the "best" solution still seems to be to have a companion extension that runs in a privileged environment that can make the requests and communicate the results with the page. The tool does a variety of other things that work within a web page so I would rather leave the primary environment as the web page with the option to run the extension.

Comment: What is your question ?? Do you have any difficulties in making Cross-Origin XHR

Comment: Yes, you cannot since browsers purposely block it. I described the various methods for making Cross-Origin requests, but there is not clean way to do them if you do not have control over the domains you are making the request to. Looking to see if I overlooked something or if there are any future plans to provide a method for web pages to request access.

Comment: Have you considered using a service similar to YQL?

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Why can't browsers just ask for permissions like this ad-hoc, rather than requiring you to install an extension/app?